# Query RDS endpoint name from within Oracle RDS SE

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, endpoint

We are converting an existing Oracle application to run with AWS RDS Oracle Standard Edition.  For support purposes, the application uses a query like `select sys_context('userenv','server_host') from dual` to retrieve the name of the server the Oracle database is actually running on. We have 100+ of these Oracle instances, and we've found that having a SQL query retrieve that information is more reliable the depending on what a user, or some configuration files, say they *should* be connected with.

The issue is, when running in an AWS RDS Oracle database, the above query only returns an internal hostname, for example, `ip-172-17-5-56`, which we find difficult to match up with the actual RDS Endpoint names.

How can we, using Oracle PL/SQL, retrieve the true RDS endpoint name that the query is running in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found the endpoint seems to be quite separate from the database itself. It's more of a DNS name that just points you there. Short of asking AWS support, I would suggest just stashing the endpoint in a table when you create the RDS instance. You could also build a little Python script to iterate through all of your RDS instances and add that table after the fact.